# Bluetooth Stopping Internet Flow in Linux

Tags: linux, audio, internet, bluetooth

**Request** (partially fixed... look at the next paragraph):
So I just tried to connect my headphones to my computer and it is doing that same thing again... I don't know why and I am really sad now because my bluetooth has gone back to being broken after only one day of it working... ***if anyone has any ideas about how to fix this please let me know, since nothing is working right now, I don't care if you aren't sure if it works, I just want ideas right now...***

***Now I am confused...*** I just tried it again today and it works fine along with internet... The only difference is the USB port that I plugged the dongle into. That shouldn't make that much of a difference should it?

**INITIAL QUESTIONS AND DETAILS:**
I have a computer that was originally Windows 7, but I messed that up, so I installed Linux Mint to hopefully try to fix my Windows 7 to upgrade to Windows 10... but I haven't gotten around to that...

My question is about the bluetooth and the internet on my computer (it is a Dell Inspiron N5110, it's a pretty old laptop). When I connect anything (**EDIT**: I've only actually tested this when I connect bluetooth headphones) to my laptop using bluetooth, it stops the "flow" of internet. Like it still shows that I am connected, but I can't load any page on my browser while I have a bluetooth device connected.

When I have bluetooth headphones connected the sound that comes through is quite crackly... I this just old hardware? Or is it something to do with Linux? Is there an easy fix or do I just need to get a new laptop?
Is there a way that I can adjust the hardware to make it work?

I have tried using a Bluetooth USB dongle, but this just fixes the crackly part... it still doesn't allow me to use the internet...

**ADDITIONAL DETAILS:**
I just got new headphones that work with bluetooth 5.0 (not sure if that makes a difference...) and the crackling stopped, but now the internet "flow" switches between on and off...

It almost seems like it is using the same device to connect to the internet as it does to connect with bluetooth devices (which makes a little sense, because both my internet connection and bluetooth are both 2.4 GHz). Is there a way to fix that (if it is the problem...)?

Now a kind of random question, does bluetooth work with Linux? Does anyone have a computer with bluetooth and Linux?

**EVEN MORE DETAILS:**
So I realized that I didn't mention that the internet signal strength will go from 0% to what it normally is at (between 70% and 100%), when it shows the signal strength normal, it loads pages fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so it seems like either no one else is having this problem or no one has figured out a solution... but today I kind of accidentally fixed the issue (the solution includes a USB Bluetooth Dongle)

So I just tried to connect my headphones to my computer and it is doing that same thing again... I don't know why and I am really sad now because my bluetooth has gone back to being broken after only one day of it working... **if anyone has any ideas about how to fix this please let me know, since nothing is working right now, I don't care if you aren't sure if it works, I just want ideas right now...**

**Solution** (At least for me):

- So I was just trying my bluetooth on my computer again to see if the
  update to Linux Mint 20.1 made any difference... I don't really know
  for sure if it did, but I can now use bluetooth and WiFi at the same
  time.
- What I did:

  - I turned on bluetooth (just from with the computer hardware, I didn't have the dongle in yet)
  - I connected my headphones and tried to play music it started to play because of the part of the music track it had already downloaded, but when I tried to go a website it didn't load and the music stopped playing soon after.
  - I plugged in my bluetooth dongle in (bluetooth was still on, but I had disconnected all devices)

    - Note: I don't know what bluetooth version it runs, I doubt that it uses 5.0, because it is quite old... I remember my dad using it when I was in grade school.
  - I turned off bluetooth, and then turned on bluetooth (this seemed to switch it from computer hardware bluetooth to dongle bluetooth, which didn't seem to do before... though I didn't do these same steps)
  - I then re-paired my computer with my headphones (when it switched to the dongle's bluetooth the paired devices were different)
  - Once I re-paired and connected, I could play music all I wanted and the internet connection didn't cut out. To test it I even got in a Microsoft Teams Meeting with my team for school and I heard sound and I was able to see and hear (in real-time... no additional lag) my teammates!

***Some more details:***
I just wanted to add a few more details that I have observed over the past few days...

- It seems to work best if you do the connecting in this way *(with the bluetooth dongle)*

  1. Have your bluetooth device turned off
  2. Plug in your bluetooth dongle (leave bluetooth off, if it is already on, turn it off)
  3. Turn on your bluetooth device (if it has a specific pairing mode, put it to that)
  4. Turn on bluetooth... your devices should automatically connect. If they do not, do it manually.

If someone else had this problem, I hope that this helped them! I would still like to figure out (and fix) the computer's bluetooth connection issues...

Answer (score 0):

I have faced with the same issue , i have changed various linux-distro , thinking it will solve the problem...

The reason behind the problem is bluetooth and wifi both use same network hardware , so one of them need to stop...

solution: use a dongle( either for wifi or for bluetooth ) then it will work perfectly fine

Comment: This is incorrect. While Wi-Fi and BT use the same card, they are entirely different technologies and protocols. While both are often located on the same card, they have separate radios and antennas.

Comment: Hello, what's the make of your wireless adapter? Confirm that first.